# Several services, Same Android app

Tags: android, refactoring, android-service

I currently maintain an Android application which uses a big fat services handling :

- Bluetooth communication (constant through App usage)
- File compression
- Http Request
- Canvas saving (the app uses Samsung Pen SDK, with huge canvas to save)

I'd like to split the service into new namely services. Should I? Am I going to slow my app by using too much memory for those services? Is it going to be mess to maintain?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If managed properly several services can decrease memmory and CPU usage. If some part of the app needs only File compression- no point for it to use everything else. 
Also services does not use alot of resources by themselves- its important what you do inside.

Look at [Intent Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) They can be usefull for your File Compression and Canvas, while normal always running service is usefull for your Bluetooth communication(if its really needed all the time).